# can't login by ssh aftcher chmod on home folder

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I've done a chmod 777 on my home folder, where the .ssh folder is, and now I cannot login.
I've restored permission on all files but still cannot login. Should I change anything in order to be able to login again.

I get this message: Server refused our key
On other servers I can login properly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssh rejects key-based logins if permissions allow other people to tamper with your authorized_keys file. You need to check /, /home, /home/yourname, /home/yourname/.ssh and /home/yourname/.ssh/authorized_keys. All of those must not be group or world writeable.

Comment: my .ssh folder and inner files were ok, but my /home/myname still was 777. Once changed to 755 it started to work again. That was the problem.

Answer (score -1):

> Typically you want the .ssh directory permissions to be 700 (drwx------) and the public key (.pub file) to be 644 (-rw-r--r--). Your private key (id_rsa) should be 600 (-rw-------).

Stolen from: [Permissions on private key in .ssh folder?](https://superuser.com/a/215506/505766)

Comment: The single server wouldn't be returning that response if this was an issue on the local end.